# Installed node package cannot be accessed

Tags: raspbian, node.js

I'm a windows developer - my knowledge of Linux and RPi are fairly basic.
When I log in and am in my home folder, I can enter

```
nodejs -v
```

and am shown that it is at 0.6x.

I saw that it is in `/usr/bin`.  The node package manager, `npm`, is also in this folder, and is displayed:

```
npm -> ../share/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

To get a newer version I followed the example at [adafruit](http://learn.adafruit.com/node-embedded-development/installing-node-dot-js), which brought down and installed the 0.12.x version - so far so good.

However, when I enter `node` from the command line, I get a

> no such file

message.  It is in `/usr/local/bin`.  If I go there, it runs from the command line - so I suspect it is some sort of pathing issue.  Is this solved by adding the directory to `.profile`?

Since `node` and `nodejs` have different names I don't forsee a conflict.  However, the `npm` in `/usr/local/bin` - the one I want to use - points to

```
npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

So, I am hoping someone can tell me the cleanest way for:

1. `node` to be executable from the command line when pointing to a location other than `/local/usr/bin`
2. `npm`, when executed from the command line, to use the version in `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH environment variable, in `.profile`:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin
```

However, the SHELL will use the first binary that it finds (when searching through the paths in the PATH environment variable, so if you put /usr/local/bin at the *start*, like so

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
```

then it will execute binaries, of the same name, which are in `/usr/local/bin` in preference to those in `/usr/bin`, for example.

If you modify your `.profile` (or .`bashrc`) and then save it, re-source it with `. .profile`, and then type `echo $PATH`, to confirm that your path has been changed.

If I understand correctly, as both of the binaries that you want to use are in `/usr/local/bin`, then this should fix your problem.

NOTE: The fact that they are links to other locations does not matter, in this case, as neither of them point to `/usr/bin`, or any other directory in your path.